# QR codes sub topic

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, coding-theory

I'm studying math and I'm starting with my degree work, for the subject, my advisor recommended me QR codes, but I can not find a current article or an interesting subtopic about it, I would like to help me with any article or sub-topic related to QR codes,

I do not know if I can ask this here, but I do not know who else can help me, I'm good with algebra, theory of numbers, groups, rings, maybe you recommend another interesting and related topic that is in research.

thanks..

Im sorry, 
I am working to improve my English

Answer (score 1):

I do not know much about QR codes unfortunately. However, since you expressed interest in possible alternative topics:

As an undergraduate, I did a research paper on Representation Theory of Finite Groups which I quite enjoyed. Another possibility, more on the coding theory side, might be Information Theory, which has a strong algebraic flavor as well. Both are very large topics with wide applications, and you would have very little trouble finding articles/books on them.